# Где хранится СТЭК?

Tags: memory

Вопрос возник во время изучения архитектуры пк. К каком типу памяти относится стэк? Стэк это абстрактный тип данных говорит вики но про то где он хранится ни слова. 
Я дошел к тому что стэк может быть или универсальным регистром или создаваться в RAM, но RAM предназначен не для этого же. Кто знает может поделиться знаниями, а то вопрос не дает покоя

Comment: А для чего же по вашему предназначена RAM. Она нужна для хранения любых оперативных данных, в том числе и самого кода программа и ее обычных данных и стека. Собственно от обычных данных стек отличается только наличием указателя на его вершину и метода работы с этим указателем

Comment: Ну по сути да, Ram выдаёт место под программу, а программа сама себе место выделяет под стэк. Вроде так логично получается. @Mike спасибо

Comment: Ну скажем на платформе x86 стек для программы создает операционка, хотя бы по тому что эта память по особому отмечена в дескрипторах сегментов, которые полностью в ведении ОС. Но операционка как первая запускающаяся программа определяет его сама себе конечно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы говорите о стеке как о хранилище параметров процедур и их локальных переменных, то да, он хранится в оперативной памяти (RAM), где ж ещё?

Если вы говорите о стеке как о структуре данных, доступных в некоторых языках, то место хранения — стек в смысле предыдущего абзаца или куча, в зависимости от многих факторов. Например, `std::stack` из C++ хранится, как и любой объект, там, где его аллоцируют, а вот свои данные он хранит скорее всего в куче. В любом случае, это тоже в оперативной памяти.

Наконец, если говорить о стеке как об абстрактной структуре данных, то его реализацию можно хранить где угодно — например, в файловой системе. Зависит лишь от желания разработчика реализации.

Comment: просто регистр тоже подходит под его запросы, быстрый, маленький и к примеру универсальный регистр хорошо подходит для хранения результат или адреса но потом вспомнил что стэк можно растянуть до 1 мегабайта с помощью рекурсии, а такие размеры не постижимы для регистров, так что сглупил

Comment: @VladimirSamoilenko: В регистрах вы можете хранить десяток чисел, а стек может расти как угодно сильно. Поэтому в регистрах вы сможете хранить максимум _указатель_ на стек, а сам стек придётся всё равно класть в оперативку.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался

Comment: @VladimirSamoilenko: Пожалуйста!